# invoke a method using the name of an other enum

Tags: java, reflection

It is possible to invoke a method using the name of an other enum.

I did this with switch case statement :

```
public static String getSnowmizLabel(SnowmizEnum snowmizEnum, SnowmizI18n snowmizI18n) {
    switch (snowmizEnum) {
        case MIZ1_SUBTYPE:
            return snowmizI18n.MIZ1_SUBTYPE();

        /*100 other cases*/ 

        case MIZ2_SUBTYPE:
            return snowmizI18n.MIZ2_SUBTYPE(MyContext.getProjectCode());
        default:
            return snowmizEnum.name();
    }
}
```

but i need to use java reflection.

Comment: The specific difficulty I see here is that you need to pass different numbers of parameters in different cases. How would you derive the parameters? I think you might find it easiest to do it explicitly (write the code for each case), with a test to ensure all cases are covered.

Comment: rather than calling `snowmizI18n.MIZ1_SUBTYPE()` i want to invoke that method using `snowmizEnum.name()` and ignoring parameters

Comment: You can't ignore the parameters. `MIZ1_SUBTYPE` takes zero; `MIZ2_SUBTYPE` takes one. Even if you call them reflectively, you still need to pass the right number of parameters.

Comment: Using `String` instances to determine logic flow and manually handle type identification is, in technical terms, insane. Why not create an abstract method in your one enum type that each instance overrides for your desired behavior?

Comment: Thank you @Andy Turner, the solution you proposed is the actual :) but i thought it will be ugly to write several lines of code for something may be done with reflection, what do you think ?

Comment: @skanso but my question is whether you *can* do it with reflection. There may be some way to automatically derive the parameters for a given method; but what if there's not?

Answer (score 0):

The specific difficulty I see here is that you need to pass different numbers of parameters in different cases. How would you derive the parameters?

I think you might find it easiest to do it explicitly (write the code for each case), with a test to ensure all cases are covered.

The pattern I use to write a test like this is what I call a "loop-and-switch"; I don't know if there's a proper name for it. As the name suggests, you loop over the enum values, and immediately switch over the loop variable:

```
for (SnowmizEnum value : SnowmizEnum.values()) {
  switch (value) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This allows you to provide value-specific checking for each value in the enum, whilst also guaranteeing that you've not missed any cases.

So, a slightly filled-out loop-and-switch test would look like:

```
for (SnowmizEnum value : SnowmizEnum.values()) {
  switch (value) {
    case MIZ1_SUBTYPE:
    case MIZ2_SUBTYPE:
    // ... + other value cases.
      // Ensure that your method works without exception in these cases.
      // Return value can be ignored, or tested if you so desire:
      // normal completion is a result in and of itself.
      getSnowmizLabel(value, snowmizI18n);
      break;

    case MIZ3_SUBTYPE:
    // ... + other value cases.
      // Ensure that your method fails for values that you expect it
      // to fail for. (You might not need this, if you expect it to
      // work in all cases)
      try {
        getSnowmizLabel(value, snowmizI18n);
        fail("Expected failure");
      } catch (SomeException expected) {}
      break;

    default:
      // Add a catch-all, so that you fail in cases you've not
      // explicitly tested.
      throw new AssertionError("Unhandled case: " + value);
  }
}
```

The obvious disadvantage of writing things out explicitly is the verbosity; but this is a 1-time cost.

The great advantage of this over reflection is that the compiler and tests ensure your code is working like you expect: it's robust to adding or removing enum values or changes to your methods' signatures, because it will simply stop compiling/the tests will stop passing. It will also work a lot more easily with language tools, like IDE refactorings, since this is just plain code, rather than some convoluted reflection hairball.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), add the commands to a keyed collection.  Do you have some specific reason for using the Enum as a key?  If not they I would key each command them on `this.getClass().getName()` in a `HashMap<K,V>`.

```
final HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
final CommandA commandA = new CommandA();
commands.put("A", commandA);
commands.get("A").execute();
```

Keyed on the Enum.

```
final HashMap<EnumKey, Command> commands = new HashMap<EnumKey, Command>();
commands.put(EnumKey.DoCommandA, new CommandA());
commands.get(EnumKey.DoCommandA).execute();
```